# Checkout Step disappeard [Shipping] - Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

I always had 2 checkout steps..

The first one where you had to fill in Shipping Information and choose a shipping option
and
the second one where you choose payment option.

Now the first step randomly disappeard and I cannot choose a shipping option anymore nor fill in shipping information.. It directly goes to the payment options..

Does someone know what I could do to get it back how it was? I didnt really change anything but it suddenly disappeard..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shipping step does not appear when there is nothing to ship.
If the products in your cart are all virtual products and/or downloadable products, there is nothing to ship so you will only need to fill in the billing details.

Comment: Ummm, just saw I had the "products" in configurable product as "virtual products".. It did that automatically when I created a configurable product.. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: edit the products and change their type. or add a weight or something. Not entirely sure how it works for Magento 2.

Comment: added weight, now it turned to a simple product. Thanks! :))